# control identifier output Tree format need to be converted into Json format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pywinauto

When we get the print control identifier, the output is in a tree format.
Is there a way to print the control identifier output in JSON format.

Current output:

```
Dialog - 'SP- HS'    (L-32000, T-32000, R-31840, B-31972)
['Dialog', 'SP- HSDialog', 'SP- HS']
child_window(title="SP- HS", class_name="#32770")
   | 
   | Static - 'SP'    (L-31885, T-31977, R-31641, B-31948)
   | ['Static', 'SP', 'SPStatic', 'Static0', 'Static1']
   | child_window(title="SP", class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - 'HS'    (L-31526, T-31977, R-30807, B-31946)
   | ['HSStatic', 'HS', 'Static2', 'HSStatic0', 'HSStatic1']
   | child_window(title="HS", class_name="Static")
```

Desired output:

```
[{
    "Name": "SP-HS",
    "co-ordinates": "L-32000, T-32000, R-31840, B-31972",
    "Alias": "['Dialog', 'SP- HSDialog', 'SP- HS']",
    "Title": "SP-HP",
    "Class_name": "#32770"
}, {
    "Name": "SP",
    "co-ordinates": "L-31885, T-31977, R-31641, B-31948",
    "Alias": " ['Static', 'SP', 'SPStatic', 'Static0', 'Static1']",
    "Title": "SP",
    "Class_name": "Static"
}]
```

I know the hard way, where we use all the string manipulation operation and convert this to JSON. But if there any other easier way, let me know .

Comment: Yes it is. If you want to know how, you should at lead say whether you have to post process a stream or a file, or if you can change the way the output is produced.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I just want to to the output to be produced by print_control_identifier.

Comment: Can you share the code that produces the current output?

Comment: `app = Application().connect(title=<TitileOfUI>, class_name='#32770')
app<TitileOfUI>.print_control_identifiers(filename=r"c:\temp\UIelements.txt")` 
This produce the respective UI ouptut in tree format . Refer current output to know how it will be

Comment: @ashtav this is great idea! I've filed feature request: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/1041 I can't promise to implement it fast, but we have a hope to include it into next major release during this year (no exact estimation when it can be released: there is still plenty of work).

Comment: @ashtav did you find any solution to this question? If yes, could you please share

Comment: @Aawan I have found solution. I don't have any idea how to share it . I will check-in to Pywinauto lib .

Comment: @ashtav Could you share the solution. Similar output is also required in my project. It would be kind if you can share the solution .